# Read column names from a csv file and subset a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to keep specific columns of a dataframe, based on desired column names. For that purpose, I have created a dataframe named **NameList** that contains the desired column names, and use *match* command to extract the desired columns from the reference dataframe, named **df**. The resulting dataframe, which is a subset of the reference dataframe, is named **NewDF**.

```
Fire <- c(42,46,29);
height <- c(21,25,28);
age <- c(23, 41, 32)
df <- data.frame(Fire,height,age);
NameList <- c("age","Fire")

idx <- match(NameList, names(df));
idx <- sort(idx)
NewDF <- df[,idx]
```

My problem is that I can not repeat this process when I am loading these names from a csv file. I fail on bringing the input data into the same format as the **NameList**. Hence, I would like to ask for your help on how to create a suitable csv file that R will read and convert the input data so that they can be used to extract the desired columns

K

Comment: Do your csvs have column names? Are they same for all csvs?

Comment: I have a csv file that has the following content:: "Name1","Name2","Name3",.... I have tried having either all names in a single line, or one name per row

Comment: What is `input_data2` ? What is `MAINDF` ? If you want to select `NameList` columns from the dataframe you can do `df[, NameList]`

Comment: sorry, I paste a modified version. MAINDF is the df,input_data2 is the NameList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem as follow:

1. Create a csv file, named columns_names.csv, that contains the desired column names (see content of the csv file below)
   RHO_1 RHO_2 RHO_3
2. Use the following code:

```
df1 <-  read.table(file = "/Users/kotsios/Desktop/RCODE_CLUSTERING/auxilliary_codes/column_names.csv")
names(df1) <- as.matrix(df1[1, ])
df1 <- df1[-1, ]

#create a dataframe:
RHO_1 <- c("Tom",    "Dick",   "Harry",  "RHO_1" ,"John","RHO_2",   "Paul",   "George","RHO_3",  "Ringo")
RHO_2 <- c(1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);RHO_3 <- c(1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);RHO_4 <- c(11, 21, 31,41,51,61,71,81,91,101)
df2 <- data.frame(RHO_1, RHO_2,RHO_3,RHO_4)

#keep the desired column names
df5 <- df2[, (colnames(df2) %in% colnames(df1)) ]
```